I want to store more than one data in a column in my PostgreSQL Database
I am designing a database for a blog content. For example, let's say I need data for a ‘bibliography’ column to be included in my blog content. A blog content can have more than one bibliography content. Or in another example, let's say I want to tag more than one user in the tag section of a blog content. How do I keep this data in my data table in such operations? Which data type should I use. I read on the internet that the array data type is not very reliable, so I thought of a method of storing data by converting JSON data into String data (I use NodeJS and I use the JSON.strigfy(data) method). I was not sure if this method is also correct. I would be very grateful if the relevant people answer my question.

Learn how to normalize your data, at least to 3NF: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

You should use relations.
for example:
we have users table
create table users{
    id primary key,
    name varchar(100)
    (...etc)
}

also we have blogs table, each user have more then one blog. we should create relation between user and blogs. we should define FOREIGN KEY in blogs table. you can read more about FOREIGN KEY => https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp
create table blogs{
    id primary key,
    content varchar(100),
    user_id int,
    foreign key (user_id) references users(id)
}

now we have blogs, where each blogs contain user_id and we can easy find who owns the blog.
According this example you can build your database models.
In SQL database like postgreSQL you should use relations between tables, you can read more about it -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/relationships-in-sql-one-to-one-one-to-many-many-to-many/
To retrieve user blogs you can use JOIN in potgresql. In node.js you can use some orm for this, like: typeorm,sequelizer and etc. but first you should know what is sql, what is joins and relations between tables in sql.
first of all read about relations and joins, when you can build some simple tables and relations, use JOINS for more practice. when you can read about orm, what is orm, why you should use it.
